# Can a SP list with a Powerapps be duplicated?

Tags: sharepoint-list, powerapp

I need to duplicate a list that has a PowerApps function to it. Can this be duplicated? We manage different products and every product should have this checklist.

Will I need to re-do this list and Powerapp every time? or can I simply duplicate the list and its functions?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a quick and easy way to duplicate a list.  You could potentially look at the [PnPProvisioning](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-provisioning-framework) PowerShell cmdlets, which would allow you to generate a template for the list that you could provision with PowerShell.

But my recommendation instead would be to just use the **one list, and add metadata** to specify the Product (either a choice column, or lookup to a Product list).  Then the all your product's checklists could be in the same list either grouped and/or filtered by Product.  Then adding a new product would just involve adding a new Product choice instead re-created a new copy of the list each time.